# How do I fix the following error code: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "cases", value =

Tags: r, truthtable

When I give the following code:

```
ttE1B <- truthTable(data=O4S2, outcome = "FSUMSUST", conditions = "CSUSCOM, 
CESGCOMP, FWOM, CENERGY, CMAT, CINDUST, CCDISC, CFINSECT, CENVSPOL, CTELE, 
CUTIL, CGRBLDGPOL, CSPKGPOL, FTOTPOL, CGRI, CUN, FESGD, FSOCD, FENVD, FGOVD",  
sort.by="incl, n", show.cases=TRUE)
```

I repeatedly get the following error code:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "cases", value = c("99,148,155,175",  : 
replacement has 77 rows, data has 167
```

I am trying to obtain truth tables for my outcome and conditions (truthTable command).  I have tried various combinations but I continue to get the above noted error when I include some (but not all) of the conditions.  I assume that the error relates to the cases mentioned (each time I run it different cases are mentioned depending on which conditions I have used in the command).

I can successfully run the command with some of the conditions but I need to run it with all of the conditions.  I tried removing the data (cases) referenced to see if that would help but it has not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, include in the question the code that is generating this error.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I'm editing it now. @JaimeCaffarel